# Java Rock Paper Scissors Lizard Spock Using Char and String

Tags: java

Hello there and thank you for any help in advance.  I'm new to Java, in my first class and have been working on this for a few days.

As you can probably tell from the title this is an expanded version of Rock, Paper, Scissors.

I wrote a great working program using string and int as the variables, but then was told I had to get user input as a char.  Now I'm having a problem getting the user input to equal the computer input.

UPDATE: I rewrote the program making comp a char.  Everything except when there is a tie now works.  The problem is the case.  Example:  userInput = r  comp=R  this should be a tie and output "It's a tie!"  I've been trying Charactor.toUpperCase and charactor.toLowerCase but I don't think I have the correct syntax so If userInput = comp the case is ignored. Can anyone give me the correct Syntax for this?  Thanks!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Rocktest
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
char userInput;
char comp;   
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter R for Rock, P for Paper, S for Scissors, L
for Lizard and K for Spock: ");
userInput = (char)System.in.read();
    keyboard.nextLine();
    int comt=(int)(5*Math.random())+1;
    comp=(' ');

    if (comt==1){
           comp=('R');
    }
    else if (comt==2){
            comp='P';
    }
    else if (comt==3){
            comp='S';
    }

    else if (comt==4){
            comp='L';
    }

    else if (comt==5){
            comp='K';
    }           


    if((userInput == 'R')||( userInput == 'r'))  
         {
          System.out.println("You choose: Rock");

    }
    else if((userInput == 'P')||(userInput == 'p')) 
          {
            System.out.println("You choose: Paper");

    }
       if((userInput == 'S')||( userInput == 's'))  
         {
          System.out.println("You choose: Scissors");

    }      
        if((userInput == 'L')||( userInput == 'l'))  
         {
          System.out.println("You choose: Lizard");              
         }            

        if((userInput == 'K')||( userInput == 'k'))  
         {
          System.out.println("You choose: Spock"); 
        }                         

   System.out.println("I choose: " + comp); //This is where I'm having the                 
                                            //problem
                                           //need to ignore case
       if (userInput==comp)                             
       {
        System.out.println("A tie!");
        }

      else if((userInput == 'R')||( userInput == 'r')) {
             if (comp == 'S')
                    System.out.println("Rock crushes scissor - you win!");
            else if (comp == 'L')
                    System.out.println("Rock crushes Lizard - you win!");
            else if (comp == 'P')
                    System.out.println("Paper covers rock - you lose!");
            else if (comp == 'K')
                    System.out.println("Spock vaporizes rock - you lose!");
    }
    else if ((userInput == 'P')||(userInput == 'p')) {
            if (comp == 'S')
                    System.out.println("Scissors cut paper- you lose!");
            else if (comp == 'K')
                    System.out.println("Paper disproves Spock - you win!");
            else if (comp == 'R')
                    System.out.println("Paper covers rock - you win!");
            if (comp == 'L')
                    System.out.println("Lizard eats paper- you lose!");
    }        
    else if((userInput == 'S')||( userInput == 's')) {
            if (comp == 'P')
                    System.out.println("Scissors cut paper - you win!");
            else if (comp == 'L')
                    System.out.println("Scissors decapitates lizard - you 
            win!");
            else if (comp == 'R')
                    System.out.println("Rock crushes scissors - you lose!");
            else if (comp == 'K')
                    System.out.println("Spock smashes scissors - you lose!");
    }        
    else if((userInput == 'L')||( userInput == 'l'))  {
            if (comp == 'P')
                    System.out.println("Lizard eats paper - you win!");
            else if (comp == 'K')
                    System.out.println("Lizard poisons Spock - you win!");
            else if (comp == 'R')
                    System.out.println("Rock crushes lizard - you lose!");
            else if (comp == 'S')
                    System.out.println("Scissors decapatates lizard - you
            lose!");
    }    
    else if ((userInput == 'K')||( userInput == 'k')) {
            if (comp == 'P')
                    System.out.println("Paper disproves Spock - you lose!");
            else if (comp == 'L')
                    System.out.println("Lizard poisons Spock - you lose!");
            else if (comp == 'R')
                    System.out.println("Spock vaporizes rock - you win!");
            else if (comp == 'S')
                    System.out.println("Spock smashes scissors - you lose!");
    }  
    //System.out.println(+ comt);    used these lines for testing
    //System.out.println(+ comp);
    //System.out.println(+ userInput);

  }//end main
}//end class
```

Comment: What is the nature of the "problem" you are having?

Comment: when comparing a String, use `.equalsIgnoreCase()` for best matching

Comment: in the body of `else if (comt==5)` you should set comp to K for spock. You should also use a char for comp since you only have a single letter and you want to compare it with the user input, which is also a char

Comment: Thanks for the help.  The problem was not being able to compile without errors.  The reason looks to be, and several have pointed it out (Thank you!), is my userInput is char and comp is string.  When I tried userInput==comp it doesn't work because there are different variables.  I'd written the original program using all string but had to change the user input to char.  I was hoping I'd only have to make minor changes but now I know I have to also change the comp to char as well.  I'm guessing I'll have to change comt from int to char as well.  Sorry for not putting more information in.

Comment: Thanks to you advice I've almost completed this program.  I changed comp to char and I get the results I'm looking for except when it's a tie.  I was able to ignore the case whenever the input and the comp were different, but not when they are equal. Everything works except when there is a tie. and the cases don't match.For Example  userInput r, comp = R  It should ignore the case and print out "It's a tie!  I've been trying .toLowerCase and .toUpperCase but I don't think I have the correct order.  Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 4):

Okay, so I believe I have found your problem.

In your code, you have the line `if (comp == 'S')`, which would work fine, assuming that the variable `comp` was a `char`. But where `comp` is a `String`, it can never be equal to the `char` S or the variable `userInput`, which is also a `char`.

Simple fix: Change the variable type of comp.

That's it. I hope this helps and I wish you luck in the world of java.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me so quickly. I was thinking along that line.  I was hoping there was some way around it.  I had written the program using string as the user input and tried to to just change that to char.  Back to the drawing board.  Thanks again.