# I need to make Rock,Paper scissors for computer science but i need to add lizard and spock

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

hi and thank you for you time, so for my class i need to make RPS lizard spock and i've gotten so far to make the basic rock paper and scissors work But i can't seem to add the lizard and spock option correctly

I've made the basic game in JS and it works perfectly i recently added the lizard and spock icons and tried to add functions to them but to no avail for them but to no avail

```
function userRock(){

    if (computerChoice === choices[0]){
        document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = 'Draw';
    }

    if (computerChoice === choices[1]){
        losses++;
        document.getElementById('losses').innerHTML = losses;
        document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = 'AI picked paper you lose';
    }

    if (computerChoice === choices[2]){
        document.getElementById('rock').setAttribute('class', 'wins');
        wins++
        document.getElementById('wins').innerHTML = 'wins';
        document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = 'AI picked scissor you win';
    }
    goComputer();
}
```

Here is a CodePen: https://codepen.io/axelnijsten/pen/rNNLjaL

I'm expecting to have the lizard and spock working correctly with only javascript

Comment: "wondering if my code can be shorter and how" - For reviews of working code, you should ask on https://codereview.stackexchange.com instead (and then remove it here).

Comment: but that leaves me with my other problem still so i'll jus remove that part

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Rock Paper Scissors Lizard Spock Using Char and String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44599282/java-rock-paper-scissors-lizard-spock-using-char-and-string)

Answer (score 0):

To make it much shorter, do something like this.. how exactly that fits with the so called Lizard, i dont know!? But if Lizard is beaten by a rock, but beats a scissor, then just add it as the fourth element in choices.

```
//give AI choices
let choices = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissor'];
let computerChoice;
let wins = 0;
let losses = 0;

//adds scores
document.getElementById('wins').innerHTML = wins;
document.getElementById('losses').innerHTML = losses;

//makes the AI pick Rock Paper or Scissor

function goComputer () {
    computerChoice = Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length);
    console.log(computerChoice);
    return computerChoice;
}

function userAction(userChoice) //0..n-1 (choices must be in order that idxN is always beaten by idxN+1, unless n is the length-1 then its beaten by idx0)
{
    //calling AI to make a move
    const computerChoice = goComputer();

    if (computerChoice === userChoice){
        document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = 'Draw';
    }
    else if (userChoice === choices.length-1 && computerChoice === 0 || userChoice !== choices.length-1 && computerChoice > userChoice)
    {
        losses++;
        document.getElementById('losses').innerHTML = losses;
        document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = 'AI picked '+choices[computerChoice]+' you lose';
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('rock').setAttribute('class', 'wins');
        wins++
        document.getElementById('wins').innerHTML = wins;
        document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = 'AI picked '+choices[computerChoice]+' you win';
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried using this one but it doesnt seem to work when i implement it

Comment: But... this is only the first step. I guess you are new to this game, but the UI-rendering should never be mixed with "Business"-logic. The method userAction should really only return a winner and what the computer choose, and then a seperate method does the rendering afterwards.

Comment: And of course the userAction(0) should be used instead of userRock(), and userAction(1) instead of userPaper() etc etc.

Comment: i'm sorry but you lost me i'm not this wellknown with these terms since this is my first year doing this

Comment: Lost you exactly by what, you can't get the code to work or?

Comment: i cant get it to work and I don't know to many terms like UI-rendering, Business-logic etc. so i'm trying my best to understand

Comment: UI is the visual stuff on your screen, business-logic is the non-visual stuff e.g. calculation or determine who wins in this game. They should be seperated later on, because the logic could and perhaps should be used within many different systems, e.g. a WindowsApplication where document.getElementById wont work. But that another chapter.

Have you changed the html-links, so e.g. userRock() is now userAction(1)?

Comment: i've changed 'em for all three users

Comment: Hmm... I've been using your codepen link and replaced the javascript, and replaced all user-action-method-calls in the HTML to use userAction(<userActionNumber>) instead, it works.
<userActionNumber> is of course 0, 1 or 2. Havent fixed anything for Lizard and Spock.

What exactly are you doing?

Comment: i've managed to get everything working i'm just trying now to get the code shorter

here is the updated codepen

Answer (score 0):

in general this looks good. There some common programming principles that you can apply here:

One principle is DRY (Don't repeat yourself), which you can use for your `document.getElementById(id).innerHTML` that you use at several places. You should create a seperate function that does this: `setInnerHTMLById(id, message)`. This makes your lines shorter, easier to read and more maintainable.

Another thing here is how you use your `if` statement: The computer can make only one choice, so instead of using 3 `if` statements, consider using `if` and `else if` statements, or a `switch` (especially when you want to add lizard and spock). This makes your code faster because it will not have to check not unneccessary ìf`s (e.g. when the first`if` statement was already true, it will not check the second and third)

With a `switch` statement implementing the new choices will be a piece of cake

Comment: so would i have to change my code entirely or just make a few changes

Comment: As people noted, you should probably use the codereview section on stack overflow (I'm new myself here) - but in general, you could do just the two small changes in order to make your code a bit better - however your code IS already working - so could just add two more `if`s for lizard and spock for every case and add additional handlers for lizard and spock and thats all

Answer (score 0):

I have changed your code a bit. There is just one function called now but it has parameter which corresponds with your choices array.

```
let choices = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissor', 'Lizard', 'Spock'];
                 0        1         2         3         4
```

Now the markup looks like this

```
<div class="main" id="rock" onclick="action(0)">
    <i class="fas fa-hand-rock"></i>
    <h3> Rock </h3>
</div>

<div class="main" id="paper" onclick="action(1)">
    <i class="fas fa-hand-paper"></i>
    <h3> Paper </h3>
</div>

<div class="main" id="scissor" onclick="action(2)">
    <i class="fas fa-hand-scissors"></i>
    <h3> Scissor </h3>
</div>

<div class="main" id="lizard" onclick="action(3)">
    <i class="fas fa-hand-lizard"></i>
    <h3> Lizard </h3>
</div>

<div class="main" id="spock" onclick="action(4)">
    <i class="fas fa-hand-spock"></i>
    <h3> Spock </h3>
</div>
```

If the user chooses an option we execute the game logic

```
const choices = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissor', 'Lizard', 'Spock'];
let wins = 0;
let losses = 0;

//adds scores
document.getElementById('wins').innerHTML = wins;
document.getElementById('losses').innerHTML = losses;

//makes the AI pick Rock Paper or Scissor
function goComputer () {     
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length);
}

function action(playerChoice) {
    // get computer choice as a number
    const computerChoice = goComputer();

    // check who won
    // draw 
    if (computerChoice === playerChoice) {
        document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = 'Draw';
    }
    // Rock
    if (computerChoice === 0 && (playerChoice === 2 || playerChoice == 3)) {
        playerLooses(computerChoice);
    } else if (playerChoice === 0 && (computerChoice === 2 || computerChoice == 3)) {
        // dry win action
        playerWins(playerChoice, computerChoice);
    }
    // paper 
    if (computerChoice === 1 && (playerChoice === 0 || playerChoice == 4)) {
        // dry loose action
        playerLooses(computerChoice);
    } else if (playerChoice === 1 && (computerChoice === 0 || computerChoice == 4)){
        playerWins(playerChoice, computerChoice);
    }
    // scissor
    if (computerChoice === 2 && (playerChoice === 1 || playerChoice == 3)) {
        playerLooses(computerChoice);
    } else if (playerChoice === 2 && (computerChoice === 1 || computerChoice == 3)) {
        playerWins(playerChoice, computerChoice);
    }
    // lizzard
    if (computerChoice === 3 && (playerChoice === 1 || playerChoice == 4)) {
        playerLooses(computerChoice);
    } else if (playerChoice === 3 && (computerChoice === 1 || computerChoice == 4)) {
        playerWins(playerChoice, computerChoice);
    }  
    //spock
    if (computerChoice === 4 && (playerChoice === 2 || playerChoice == 0)) {
        playerLooses(computerChoice);
    } else if (playerChoice === 4 && (computerChoice === 2 || computerChoice == 0)) {
        playerWins(playerChoice, computerChoice);
    }        
}

function playerLooses(computerChoice) {
    losses++;
    document.getElementById('losses').innerHTML = losses;
    document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = `AI picked ${choices[computerChoice]} you lose`;
}

function playerWins(playerChoice, computerChoice) {
    wins++;
    document.getElementById(choices[playerChoice].toLowerCase()).setAttribute('class', 'wins');
    document.getElementById('wins').innerHTML = wins;
    document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = `AI picked ${choices[computerChoice]} you win`;
}
```

We still make use of the array for getting the right element and the output text.